# API to open file from extension folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to embed a DLL file into VS Code extension and open it runtime when extension is activated.

I can include DLL file into vsix extension easily , but want to know how can I access it at runtime.

While extension debug the current direcory is 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code'

I guess I can open access the file if I can get current execution direcory and then append path like

```js
var cwd = GetCurrentWorkingDirectory(); //to be found out
var dllPath = vscode.Uri.file(cwd+'\resources\app\extensions\myextension\dist');
```

Is there an VS Code extension API which will give me current extension root directory or else VS Code installation directory?

Comment: GL running DLL code from the extension. VSC only runs JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. VSC is built on electron which supports this.I got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension Path can be obtained by context object which is passed to activate function; `context.extensionPath` which is a string or `context.extensionUri`

Alternatively,

[`env.appRoot`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#env.appRoot)

It can be accessed like

`var cwd = vscode.env.appRoot;`

maps to `VS Code\resources\app`

If system installation `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app`

if User installation `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app`

Comment: Alternatively, the entry `activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext)` gives you the `context` object. With it, you can always call `asAbsolutePath()` to convert relative paths (to the extension installation folder) to the full paths you want.

Comment: You mean `context.extensionPath` or `context.extensionUri`?
asAbsolutePath is showing debug path which I am not interested in